# can't get rid of arrow in python using turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle, pong

im trying to build a pong game but i cant get rid of a line

```
import turtle

sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
sc.title("pong")
sc.bgcolor("black")


def paddle_a():
    paddle = turtle.Turtle()
    paddle.color("white")
    paddle.shape("square")
    paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=2)
    paddle.goto(-400, 0)
    paddle.speed(0)
    paddle.penup()


def paddle_b():
    pass

while True:
    paddle_a()
    sc.update()
```

ive tried turtle.turtlehide() but no luck

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you move turtle to `(-400, 0)`, the pen is down, it will draw line. Solution is to move `penup()` method before the movement.

```py
def paddle_a():
    paddle.penup()         # <--- Move here
    paddle.goto(-400, 0)
    paddle.speed(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to lift the pen up at the correct position (before the `goto`).

I added a penup in the correct place for you (it is commented in the code below).

```py
import turtle

sc = turtle.Screen()
sc.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
sc.title("pong")
sc.bgcolor("black")


def paddle_a():
    paddle = turtle.Turtle()
    paddle.color("white")
    paddle.shape("square")
    paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=2)
    paddle.penup()    # <------------------------- added a penup here
    paddle.goto(-400, 0)
    paddle.speed(0)
    paddle.penup()


def paddle_b():
    pass

while True:
    paddle_a()
    sc.update()
```